# R: return column using get() and paste()

Tags: r, indexing

Why does `get()` in combination with `paste()` work for dataframes but not for columns within a dataframe? how can I make it work?

```
ab<-12
get(paste("a","b",sep=""))
# gives: [1] 12

ab<-data.frame(a=1:3,b=3:5)
ab$a
#gives: [1] 1 2 3

get(paste("a","b",sep=""))
# gives the whole dataframe

get(paste("ab$","a",sep=""))
# gives: Error in get(paste("ab$", "a", sep = "")) : object 'ab$a' not found
```

Comment: Serious question: why are you doing this?

Comment: You _could_ do this with `eval(parse(text = ...))`, but the degree to which R is making this awkward and difficult should be a signal that your whole approach of using `get` is probably not ideal.

Comment: simply because `$` is a function and `get` doesn't evaluate the objects passed to it, try it with `c` : `get("c(1,2,3)")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Columns in dataframes are not first class objects. Their "names" are really indexing values for list-extraction. Despite the understandable confusion caused by the existence of the `names` function, they are not true R-names, i.e. unquoted tokens or symbols, in the list of R objects. See the `?is.symbol` help page. The `get` function takes a character value, and then looks for it in the workspace and returns it for further processing.

```
> ab<-data.frame(a=1:3,b=3:5)
> ab$a
[1] 1 2 3
> get(paste("a","b",sep=""))
  a b
1 1 3
2 2 4
3 3 5
> 
> # and this would be the way to get the 'a' column of the ab object

get(paste("ab",sep=""))[['a']]
```

If there were a named object `target` with a value "a" tehn you could also do:

```
target <- "a"
get(paste("ab",sep=""))[[target]]  # notice no quotes around target 
                                   # because `target` is a _real_ R name
```

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't work because `get()` interprets the string it's passed as referring to an object named `"ab$a"` (not as referring to the element named `"a"` of the object named `"ab"`) . Here's probably the best way to see what that means:

```
ab<-data.frame(a=1:3,b=3:5)
`ab$a` <- letters[1:3]
get("ab$a")
# [1] "a" "b" "c"
```